# How to toggle antd Typography.Paragraph ellipsis

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using the `<Typography.Paragraph>` component to display the description of some items in a list. I want to limit the number of rows in the description to 2.

Now I can use the `ellipsis` prop for the `<Typography.Paragraph>` to limit the description to only display 2 lines and set it to be expandable. However, I cannot seem to find a way to collapse the text back to just 2 rows with an ellipsis `(...)`

This is a snippet of my current code.

```js
const listOfLongText = [.....];

listOfLongText.map((text,i) => {
    <Paragraph ellipsis={{ rows: 2, expandable: true }}> 
        {text}
    </Paragraph>
})
```

I know about the `onExpand` callback for the `ellipsis` prop of `Paragraph` but not sure how to get the toggle between expand and collapse functionality using `onExpand`

The `<Typography.Paragraph>` API is defined [here](https://ant.design/components/typography/#Typography.Paragraph)

If you need more information, drop a comment and I will provide it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such option in the current `antd` version (`3.23.4`).

You need to control it via state for example:

```
<Paragraph
  ellipsis={{
    rows: 3,
    expandable: true,
    onExpand: this.typoExpand
  }}
>
  Ant Design, a design language for background applications, is refined by Ant
  UED Team. Ant Design, a design language for background applications, is
  refined by Ant UED Team. Ant Design, a design language for background
  applications, is refined by Ant UED Team. Ant Design, a design language for
  background applications, is refined by Ant UED Team. Ant Design, a design
  language for background applications, is refined by Ant UED Team. Ant Design,
  a design language for background applications, is refined by Ant UED Team.
</Paragraph>;
```

[image: Edit Q-58151314-ExpandEllipsis]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you provide some pseudocode of how to make the `typoExpand` function? @Dennis

Comment: its in the answer just click on the sandbox button

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm late, but if anyone is interested, here is my answer:

```
    <div>
        <Paragraph
            ellipsis={
                !expand ? {
                    expandable: false,
                    rows: 3,
                } : false
            }>Your text here</Paragraph>
        <Button
            type="link"
            onClick={() => setExpand(prev => !prev)}
        >{expand ? "Hide" : "Show"}</Button>
    </div>
```

**INFO:** answer suits only if text is longer than 3 lines